# Unable to Append Text of XML Doc in Perl with XML::LibXML

Tags: xml, perl, parsing, nodes, xml-libxml

I am attempting to Append the Values of an XML document using perl and XML::LibXML. The XML document has multiple time settings that I need to change to a new time but I am unable to get my program to make the change. Currently, it will load the XML file and can print it to a new document but it will not update the setting I wish to change. I am kind of new to parsing in perl, I have written an excel parser before but this XML parser is giving me issues.

Can you please point out where I may be making a mistake or if I am missing something?

Here is an example of the XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' ?><Settings xmlns='http://hme.com/Settings.xsd'>
  <Setting SID="0">
    <Name>Store ID</Name>
    <Value>72</Value>
  </Setting>
  <Setting SID="1">
    <Name>Deprecated</Name>
    <Value>0</Value>
  </Setting>
 <Setting SID="8">
    <Name>Open Store Hours Sunday</Name>
    <Value>23400</Value>
  </Setting>
```

This is the code I am using to attempt to change the time from  and change the value below in between value and /value to 109800. When I run the program it runs without throwing any errors but also does not update the value.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $settings_file = 'C:\Users\tstevens\Desktop\timer_test\08449.xml';
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
my $files = 'C:\Users\tstevens\Desktop\timer_test\08449.xml';

my $doc = $parser->parse_file($settings_file) or die "Couldn't parse timer settings\n";

for my $reviewer ($doc->findnodes('/Setting[@SID="8"]/Name/Value')) {
  my ($name) = $reviewer->findnodes('Value');
  $name->removeChildNodes;
  $name->appendText('109800');  
}

open (OUTFILE, ">>$files");                 
print OUTFILE $doc;


print "XML outputted to File";
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The `Value` element is not inside the `Name` element, so `Name` should not be in the hierarchy.

Inside the `for` loop, the `$reviewer` node looks for another element called `Value`, so you should not include `Value` in the call to `$doc->findnodes` either.

It is also not clear whether your `<Setting>` elements are at the top level. It may be necessary to use the path `/Settings/Setting...` or `//Setting...`

```
...
for my $reviewer ($doc->findnodes('//Setting[@SID="8"]')) {
    my ($name) = $reviewer->findnodes('Value');
    ...
```

Comment: When attempting to run it with both /Settings/Setting... or //Setting... I get the following error parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
<Settings xmlns="http://hme.com/Settings.xsd">

Comment: as well as this error 26573: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
</Settings><?xml version="1.0"?>

Comment: Try to use a valid XML document as input. It probably doesn't help that your script appends the corrected document to the original document.

Comment: I did suspect that and loaded a fresh xml in that has not been overwritten, once I used a valid input file the error went away but I am still unable to get the value to change.

Comment: So I have identified the issue, my top settings value in the XML is <settings xmlns='http://hme.com/Settings.xsd'>. If i remove the URL from the settings bracket it runs without issue. Is there a way to handle for this URL?